# Adding Same Data in DataGridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```
int? productID = null;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    productID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["MaterialID"].ToString());
}
if (productID == Convert.ToInt32(dr["MaterialID"]))
//if (productID == Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListproduct.SelectedValue))
{
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('This Product already exist')</script>");

}
else
{

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    GridViewPR.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewPR.DataBind();
    Session["DataTablePR"] = dt;

    //Qtyy.Text = "";
    //btn_Save.Visible = true;
}
```

I have Data Grid view which do not allow or alert user that data is repeating in the new row but i want to alert user to select same data for the next row not the new data.What condition should I apply?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Kindly be more clear about your question. Also add complete code.

Comment: @mjwills, code above don't allow user to add repeated data of a specific column in grid view row. but i only want to add repeated data in a specific column. what to change in code??

Comment: @GaganDeep , code above don't allow user to add repeated data of a specific column in grid view row. but i only want to add repeated data in a specific column. what to change in code??